# mysql stored procedure to allocate confirmed quanitity according to ordered quantity?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I allocate confirmed quanitity according to ordered quantity?
Also I would like to save more or less quantity in one table.

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fd97
Thanks guys!

I have 2 tables:

### orders

```
+----------+--------------+-----+
| order_id | product_code | qty |
+----------+--------------+-----+
| 23       | A1           | 3   |
| 34       | A1           | 1   |
| 54       | A1           | 7   |
| 55       | A1           | 2   |
| 60       | B1           | 4   |
| 72       | B1           | 10  |
| 80       | C1           | 2   |
| 85       | E1           | 1   |
+----------+--------------+-----+
```

### order_confirms

```
+-------+--------------+-----+
| oc_id | product_code | qty |
+-------+--------------+-----+
| 268   | A1           | 6   |
| 522   | A1           | 1   |
| 1093  | A1           | 2   |
| 1354  | A1           | 7   |
| 1580  | B1           | 1   |
| 1690  | C1           | 3   |
| 1820  | D1           | 1   |
+-------+--------------+-----+
```

### expected results:

```
+----+----------+--------------+-----+-------+--------------+
| id | order_id | product_code | qty | oc_id | confirm_type |
+----+----------+--------------+-----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | 23       | A1           |   3 | 268   | ok           |
|  2 | 34       | A1           |   1 | 268   | ok           |
|  3 | 54       | A1           |   2 | 268   | ok           |
|  4 | 54       | A1           |   1 | 522   | ok           |
|  5 | 54       | A1           |   2 | 1093  | ok           |
|  6 | 54       | A1           |   2 | 1354  | ok           |
|  7 | 55       | A1           |   2 | 1354  | ok           |
|  8 | NULL     | A1           |   3 | 1354  | over         |
|  9 | 60       | B1           |   1 | 1580  | ok           |
| 10 | 60       | B1           |   3 | NULL  | less         |
| 11 | 72       | B1           |  10 | NULL  | less         |
| 12 | 80       | C1           |   2 | 1690  | ok           |
| 13 | NULL     | C1           |   1 | 1690  | over         |
| 14 | NULL     | D1           |   1 | 1820  | over         |
| 15 | 85       | E1           |   1 | NULL  | less         |
+----+----------+--------------+-----+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: I don't see how you can get to your expected result from the data. For example B1 has 2 entries in orders, 1 in orders_confirmed but 4 in expected result how so? In particular why does order 72 split to 9,1?

Comment: It was a typo, I modified the table accordingly, B1 should have 1 row, equal to 10